# Facebook-PHP SDK 3.0 : How do I store a session in the database once the user has logged in and provided the access?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK 3.0

I would like to know how could I store the session of the user in the database so that once the user provides access and logs in, I could store the access tokens in the database and use it next time so that the user doesn't require to log in again. Right now I am using the following code

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => SECRET,
            'cookie' => true
            ));
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

         if(!$user)
        {
             $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

             echo anchor($loginUrl,"login");
        }

        //print_r($_SESSION);
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if($user)
        {
            try 
            {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
                //print_r($user_profile);
            } 
            catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
            {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }
```

Any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook access keys expire after a while. Even if you do store them, and they have not expired yet, they will not work if the user is not logged in. If you want to access the users Facebook account while the user is offline, you need the 'offline_access' permmission.

Comment: side note: I would not recommend asking for the offline_access permmission, unless you realy need it. Users don't like to grant this permmission.

Comment: Yes I already know about that and I am asking that permission would you like to tell me how to proceed from there

Comment: Now that I think about it, the offline_access token will not help you log the user back in. It only allows you to access the user's profile indefinitely. I'm not sure you can log the user in to Facebook automaticlly, if he is not logged in.

Comment: Considering FB policy on other things, I'd say not. Since logging the user in to FB includes creating a cookie from the FB domain, I'm not sure it's possible at all.